# Using CCTV SDK for Windows on Android?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, header-files

A DVR I bought includes its SDK which gives me all the programming codes for the DVR.

The example I found in the SDK was made for Windows only, is there a way I can implement these methods on Android using NDK?

The SDK uses `.cpp` files and some `.h` files. It also links to an external `.dll` file which I have no way of reading the codes to implement to Android

**EDIT**

I'm trying to implement these methods for a live view application. I managed to get the stream using `rtsp` with low latency using a different source, but I need to get the playback function which is available in the SDK

**EDIT 2**

What I mean by "playback" is to play the recorded videos saved on the hard disk of the DVR.

I asked some of my connections and they confused "playback" with "livestream" so this might also confuse some who reads this question

Comment: How those communicate? TCP/IP, Bluetooth, other?

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki I editted my question, thank you for your time

Comment: You could use Wireshark/Fiddler to look at the communictaion if it is over normal network, maybe ask the producer for API doc, read the .cpp and .h files. You can ask the developer of the dll for sources or API.